# share single onedrive account between two user accounts on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, permissions, user-accounts, onedrive

I use two user accounts on my Mac, one for work and other personal. Currently, if I put the onedrive folder in shared user folder, I can only access and have read&write permissions from one user account. If I change the permissions to access from the second account, I can't access the files from the first account. Is there a way to work around this and share files  from one onedrive account with read&write permissions for multiple user accounts on Mac?

OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To access the files from two different accounts:

1. Make a folder for OneDrive in a non-user branch of filesystem, for example:

   ```
   mkdir /usr/local/onedrive
   ```

   <sup>It is not really necessary but makes the configuration cleaner. You might as well follow with a OneDrive's directory under one user's home.</sup>

   <sup>You can use either user to create the folder, if you want to change owner later, use `chown`.</sup>
2. Change the permissions of the folder to `775` with `chmod`:

   ```
   chmod -R 775 /usr/local/onedrive
   ```

   <sup>`-R` is not necessary if you followed step 1, but if you already had files below, it would recursively set the permissions/group ownership for directories and files below.</sup>
3. Ensure the directory belongs to a group which two accounts are member of (by `staff` would be a good choice if you were the only user of the machine):

   ```
   chgrp -R staff /usr/local/onedrive
   ```
4. Configure OneDrive to use that folder in OneDrive -> Preferences -> Choose Folder.

And to clarify: this above will not allow you to run a clients on two accounts separately. OneDrive is a user application and stores its internal data under user's `~/Library`.