# Sharing OneDrive for Business on multiple Windows accounts

Tags: windows-7, windows, sync, onedrive

How can I share the same OneDrive for Business folder (same login) across multiple user accounts on a Windows machine?

`TL;DR`

One of my clients has a business where several Windows users need access to a shared set of files, which are currently shared on a file server on the network.

Currently the Windows machines are connected to a domain run on SBS. But they want to get rid of the local server and move to the cloud, leaving the domain behind for good.

They only have a handful of computers and several Windows users on each machine. All the accounts on each machine (and on all machines) basically need access to the same OneDrive for Business folder.

By default, OneDrive sticks the folder somewhere under the `C:\Users\User` folder.  Of course if I let that happen, the files will be replicated many times on the same machine by the Sync client. I intend to log-in to OneDrive Sync Client under a single username on all accounts on all machines.  Everyone needs access to the same set of files.

[There was a solution posted for a similar question on OSX](https://superuser.com/q/1060708/551243). Would the same thing work on Windows machines?

Can I set the same `non-user` folder in the OneDrive for Business Sync Client in all accounts e.g. `C:\OneDrive` and avoid replicating files in every Windows user account?

**EDIT:** An issue cropped up testing this approach. When I try to point a second Windows-user Sync client at C:\OneDrive configured in the first user account, the following error is issued:

`Cannot create OneDrive folder in the location specified: A folder named OneDrive - User already exists in the C:\OneDrive folder. Select a different location.`

Comment: For the folder exists issue, I created the folder in the default location, then changed it in the registry afterwards.  The key name was called `TargetFolderPath` - though I can't say for certain that this is 100% safe!

Comment: No answers? This is badly needed: Our family of four shares one Notebook. We have 450GB of data that we share. No ultrabook I know has room for 1.8TB of data!